# overflow: auto is hiding fixed elements in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I've tried to create a modal dialog ui control. Inside of this dialog there is a Close-Icon and a button bar. Both of these elements should be visible at all time and stay on the same position. So I created a solution with `position:fixed` and `transform: translateZ(0)` to align these element with the parent. 
The content of the dialog could be longer than the viewport so it should be scrollable.For this I've added `overflow: auto`.
On Chrome it works like intended but on Firefox fixed elements are not visible anymore. When inspecting the page with devtools the elements are on the right position, which is strange.

Here is a codepen which reproduces the behaviour: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VVvoBZ

It seem's like Firefox has a problem with `display: flex` and `overflow: auto` in combination, because it's showing the elements when using `display: box`.

Does anybody know, if this problem is a bug on my side or in Firefox?

Comment: Regardless of bug or not, I would disagree with that “solution” to begin with. Those elements are supposed to be fixed in regard to the modal element they belong to, yes? That is what absolutely positioning them inside a relative positioned parent would achieve already, so I don’t see what this (counter-intuitive) workaround is supposed to be good for to begin with …?

Comment: @misorude: Yes you're right. Haven't seen the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug because if you change their position to anything, and then back to fixed, they will become visible. Here's a hacky solution to your problem using an animation that does just that:

```
.closeicon,
.buttonbar {
    animation: ffhack 5ms;
}
@keyframes ffhack {
    from {
        position: absolute;
    }

    to {
        position: fixed;
    }
}
```